# how to detect wallet change in JS when i connect with Solflare extention

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, solana, nft

hello guys am working on a blockchain app that uses many wallets extensions like phantom , slope , solflare ...
now i authorize only few public keys to be connected to my app , but the problem is if i connect with an authorized public key i can change to unauthorized one from the extension (SOLFLARE) and do what i want , please how can i detect current public key in solflare for example when using phantom here is how to access it :

```
window.solana.publicKey
```

any way to access solflare like that or any other solution i need the public key or an event that i can attach to it ...

Answer (score 0):

hello guys i just figured it out , it's the same thing we can access it using :

```
window.solflare.publicKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
solflareLogin();

async function solflareLogin() {
    window.solflare.connect();
    window.solflare.on("connect", () => console.log("connected!"));
    setTimeout(() => {
        const wallet   = window.solflare.publicKey.toString();
        console.log( wallet );
    }, 100);

}
```